# Ui-Routes pegar o id do usuario logado

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives, angularjs-scope, angular-module, ui-router

Estou utilizando *ANGULARJS/UI-ROUTES*, e atualmente minha aplicação após logar só fica com o e-mail, preciso que também venha o ID do usuário logado. A questão das rotas eu consigo, o problema é que ele não enxerga o *ID* pra poder trazer.
Creio que o problema pode ser nas minhas *claims*?

**segue código.**

Aqui é onde eu passo o id (que está nulo, porque "user" só vem o email)

```
<li ng-show="user"><a ui-sref="perfil({userId:user.id})">OLÁ, <em>{{ user }}</em></a></li>
```

Aqui é meu controller que tento pegar o id do parametro que passe, mas só vem nulo porque o user.id está nulo

```
angular.module('scases').controller('PerfilCtrl', PerfilCtrl);

PerfilCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'UserFactory', '$stateParams'];

function PerfilCtrl($scope, UserFactory, $stateParams) {

    $scope.id = $stateParams.userId;
```

A minha verdadeira pergunta é : 
Onde eu vou pegar o id do usuário logado, se quando eu logo, só vem o e-mail?

Comment: Preserve o usuário em um *service* ou *factory*, e a partir de seus controllers verifique se o serviço possui algum usuário registrado ou não.

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizando esse `ui-sref="perfil({userId: '{{user.id}}'})"`. Confira se esse estado espera pelo parâmetro userId.

```js
.state('perfil', {
    url: '/perfil',
    templateUrl: 'perfil.html',
    controller: 'Perfil',
    params: {
        userId: null
    }
})
```

Pra conseguir o Id do usuário, você deve criar um serviço que retorne os dados que precisa.
Após obter esses dados, guarde-os no localstorage e crie um service pra disponibilizar esses dados pra você.

Exemplo:

```js
angular.module('app').service('UsuarioService', UsuarioService);

UsuarioService.$inject = ['Restangular'];

function UsuarioService(Restangular) {
    var service = {
        getUsuario: function () {
            var promise = Restangular.one('usuarios').get();

            promise.then(function (response) {
                window.localStorage.setItem('usuario', JSON.stringify(response.data.plain()));
                return response.data;
            });

            return promise;
        },
        getUsuarioFromLocalStorage: function () {
            return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('usuario'));
        }
    };

    return service;
}
```